# How to filter limit nested arrays of objects in graphql?

Tags: graphql

Sorry for novice question. I'd like to filter output of nested arrays of objects.
Here is my query:

```
properties {
  codes {
    id
  }
}
```

and it returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "properties": [
      {
        "codes": [
          {
            "id": "1"
          },
          {
            "id": "2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "codes": [
          {
            "id": "3"
          },
          {
            "id": "4"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to filter output where id = "1" in properties.codes. So new query is this:

```
properties {
  codes (id: "1") {
    id
  }
}
```

and output still has an empty "codes" array:

```
{
  "data": {
    "properties": [
      {
        "codes": [
          {
            "id": "1"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "codes": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How would I properly filter the output? I need to get this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "properties": [
      {
        "codes": [
          {
            "id": "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `codes (id: "1")` filters [existing] `codes` content ... it looks like you need to resolve it at higher/parent level, e.g. `properties( where: { codes: { contains_id: "1"}}}){ codes {...` or simply `properties( codesId: "1"){ codes {...`, depends on requred filtering complexity/flexibility

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle this within your resolver function. You haven't mentioned your preferred language so I provide a simple JavaScript/ES6 resolver:

```js
// Dummy data
const data = {
  properties: [
    {
      "codes": [
        { "id": "1" },
        { "id": "2" },
        { "id": "3" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "codes": [
        { "id": "3" },
        { "id": "4" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

// grab the id param from the arguments
const resolve = ({ id }) => {
  // retrieve the data
  const { properties: props } = data
  const result = []

  // filter data
  const properties = props.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const codes = cur.codes.filter(code => code.id === id)
    if (codes.length) {
      acc.push({ codes })
    }
    return acc
  }, [])

  return {
    properties
  }
}

console.log(resolve({ id: "1" }))
console.log(resolve({ id: "3" }))
```

Comment: this is what I already do in my resolver function (JavaScript). I just thought it can be done through the query/variables itself

Comment: GraphQL, resolvers, etc. don't do anything except call any resolver functions and pass in the arguments (or return null if there isn't one). There's no "magic" in there for filtering or anything. There may be if you're using some kind of framework that can handle your datastore, but that's not a GraphQL thing.